# How do I disable line numbers in Helm buffers?

Tags: emacs

I'm using `linum` to show line numbers. What I want is to have them enabled by default, but disabled in certain major modes, like eshell, compilation, etc.

[This](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc7) works well, but what I can't figure out is how to disable them in Helm buffers.

- There doesn't seem to be a major mode I can hook into
- `(add-hook 'helm-before-initialize-hook '(lambda () (linum-mode 0)))` turns off line numbers globally. Not sure how to disable `linum` for the current buffer only, since Helm buffers usually appear alongside another one
- Tried advice around `helm-find-files`, but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have `linum-off` set up properly. It overrides a function which `global-linum-mode` calls, so the latter has to be active in order for it to work.

```
; init.el
(require 'linum-off)
(global-linum-mode t)
```